# Convert from google sheet to android strings file.xml

Tags: android, xml

Is there any tool to convert from a google sheet file to Android strings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps for your requirement.

Step 1: Download csv file from google sheet.
-- It's easy.

Step 2: Convert CSV to strings.xml file.
-- You could refer following url.

https://github.com/LiewJunTung/Android-strings-xml-csv-converter